# Interpreting outcome of CountVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, countvectorizer

I want to create a bag of words of the text of movies I have stored in a pandas object named top100. My pandas object is having 3 columns:

- 'Name' = The title of the movie
- 'Text' = A text of approximately 500 words that describes the movie
- 'Genre' = The genre of the movie

I now want to create a bag-of-words of the column 'Text' for every movie in my dataframe using the CountVectorizer function from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

bow = CountVectorizer().fit(top100["Text"])
bow.vocabulary_
```

This return one dictionary with all the words having extreme values:

```
{u'raining': 6487,
 u'chieko': 1373,
 u'yellow': 9122,
 u'four': 3320,
 u'woods': 9058,
 u'hanging': 3748,
 u'francesca': 3330,
 u'increase': 4163,
 u'electricity': 2667,
 u'doppelg\xe4nger': 2495,
 u'lori': 4886,
 u'demoted': 2164,
 u'lord': 4883,
 u'immature': 4088,
.....
```

I tried various things but I dont know how to interpret this outcome. Even when I type 2 small sentences and try to create a word-cloud out of this it creates one dictionary with all the words and some high values.

#### What I actually want CountVectorizer to return

Shouldn't the function create a dictionary for each movie. The keys of this dictionary should be all the words that appear in all the texts of the mobies combined. The values should be how much times these words appear in the text of this one specific movie.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
bow = cv.fit_transform(top100["Text"])
r = pd.SparseDataFrame(bow, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), 
                       index=top100.index, default_fill_value=0)

print(r)  # this will help you to undestand how CountVectorizer works...
```

NOTE: this solution needs Pandas 0.20.0+ version.